# Microsoft Exchange Management console, Initilization Failed

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, exchange, powershell, winrm

Upon starting Exchange Management Console I am presented with the error

```
[###################] Connecting to remote server failed with the following error message : The WinRM client
sent a request to an HTTP server and got a response saying the requested HTTP URL was not available. This is usually re
turned by a HTTP server that does not support the WS-Management protocol. For more information, see the about_Remote_Tr
oubleshooting Help topic.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.Manageme....RemoteRunspace:RemoteRunspace) >[], PSRemotingTransportExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PSSessionOpenFailed
```

After spending some time googling, most of the problems were resolved by correcting the bindings on port 80.  I did this by following these instructions [here (Microsoft Support)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2027062).

I've run out of ideas of how to fix this problem and would appreciate if someone could shed some light or point me in a good direction.  Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you opening an EMC in the same Exchange server? Or is it in another computer?

If you are trying to run it from a different computer, try opening an admin Powershell session on your exchange CAS server(s) and type this command `winrm` /`quickconfig`. This will enable winRM on the server to allow it to receive remote powershell sessions.
Hope it works!